# How to sort array of multiple object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of multiple objects, and each object has multiple arrays inside it.

So I want to sort my array in such a way so that the object which has the highest length will come on the first and then lowest length object in the second and so on.

Here is the example object which I have.

```
    { 
      'ac17ba5a-debd-11e6-8865-2ce98f73fd2e': 
        [ ({
            startDateEvent: '1531912846801',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
            id: '9e1c9050-8a7c-11e8-a0fb-dfe60e819f99',
            _score: null })
        ],
      '01e86d5b-b1c2-11e6-9fd3-ccd35b832320': 
        [ ({
           startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
           state: 'paused',
           user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
           isDeleted: 0,
           createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
           updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
           id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
           _score: null 
           }),
          ({ 
           startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
           state: 'paused',
           user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
           isDeleted: 0,
           createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
           updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
           id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
           _score: null
           })
        ],
      '0be8235b-b1c2-11e6-9f43-ccd35b8323ww':
        [ 
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
           _score: null
          }),
          ({ 
            startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
            id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
            _score: null
          }),
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
            _score: null
          }),
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
            _score: null
          }),
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
            _score: null
          })
        ],
      '8faf05cc063f-11e8-11e6-9f43-a6fd5780':
        [ 
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
            _score: null
          }),
          ({ 
            startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
            id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
            _score: null
          }),
          ({
            startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
            state: 'paused',
            user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
            isDeleted: 0,
            createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
            id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
            _score: null
          })
       ]
    }
```

So in the result, I want to display my array like:-

```
{ 
  '0be8235b-b1c2-11e6-9f43-ccd35b8323ww':
    [ 
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
       _score: null
      }),
      ({ 
        startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      })
    ],
      '8faf05cc063f-11e8-11e6-9f43-a6fd5780':
    [ 
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({ 
        startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      })
   ],
     '01e86d5b-b1c2-11e6-9fd3-ccd35b832320': 
    [ ({
       startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
       state: 'paused',
       user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
       isDeleted: 0,
       createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
       updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
       id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
       _score: null 
       }),
      ({ 
       startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
       state: 'paused',
       user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
       isDeleted: 0,
       createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
       updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
       id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
       _score: null
       })
    ],
      'ac17ba5a-debd-11e6-8865-2ce98f73fd2e': 
    [ ({
        startDateEvent: '1531912846801',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
        id: '9e1c9050-8a7c-11e8-a0fb-dfe60e819f99',
        _score: null })
    ],
    }
```

So the sorting result should be generated based on the data inside each object keys.

Any Idea?

Comment: also what will have if two length is same for two or more case

Comment: Now i have edit my question, with the expected result

Comment: The result code you wrote is not an Array but an Object. Objects have their properties not in a sorted order, they usually get printed by lexicographical order of the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have tentatively converted your sample data into valid data. In Javascript, Arrays do not have properties, while Objects do.

I have also fixed a few other typos and given a better indentation.

The extra parentheses around objects are just to make 100% sure they are not accidentally misinterpreted as labelled statements, which should be fine since they have multiple properties anyway. I found it useful to tidy the original disorder.

Below find a snippet to illustrate my solution. Hit run, to see result with comments.

```js
let unsortedObj =
{ 
  'ac17ba5a-debd-11e6-8865-2ce98f73fd2e': 
    [ ({
        startDateEvent: '1531912846801',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T11:20:46.805Z',
        id: '9e1c9050-8a7c-11e8-a0fb-dfe60e819f99',
        _score: null })
    ],
  '01e86d5b-b1c2-11e6-9fd3-ccd35b832320': 
    [ ({
       startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
       state: 'paused',
       user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
       isDeleted: 0,
       createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
       updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
       id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
       _score: null 
       }),
      ({ 
       startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
       state: 'paused',
       user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
       isDeleted: 0,
       createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
       updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
       id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
       _score: null
       })
    ],
  '0be8235b-b1c2-11e6-9f43-ccd35b8323ww':
    [ 
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
       _score: null
      }),
      ({ 
        startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      })
    ],
  '8faf05cc063f-11e8-11e6-9f43-a6fd5780':
    [ 
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({ 
        startDateEvent: '1531903917998',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T08:51:58.007Z',
        id: 'd4224380-8a67-11e8-8589-51d5cd7a6412',
        _score: null
      }),
      ({
        startDateEvent: '1531905095516',
        state: 'paused',
        user: 'a6fd5780-67e6-11e8-b06d-8faf05cc063f',
        isDeleted: 0,
        createdAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        updatedAt: '2018-07-18T09:11:35.526Z',
        id: '91fd6770-8a6a-11e8-93db-3937d0476050',
        _score: null
      })
   ]
}
      console.log("These are the depth-1 keys sorted in descending order by number of data objects:");
      let sorted = Object.keys(unsortedObj).sort((a,b)=>{return unsortedObj[a].length<unsortedObj[b].length;});
      console.log(sorted);
      console.log("And by using map, here's the complete array");
      console.log(sorted.map(e=>{ return ({[e]: unsortedObj[e]});}));
```

Comment: You did the sorting based on their key, But i need the sorting based on their data
like key "0be8235b-b1c2-11e6-9f43-ccd35b8323ww" have have 5 object, "01e86d5b-b1c2-11e6-9fd3-ccd35b832320" have 2 object, "8faf05cc063f-11e8-11e6-9f43-a6fd5780" have 3 object and "ac17ba5a-debd-11e6-8865-2ce98f73fd2e" have one object
so it should be  sorted like  "0be8235b-b1c2-11e6-9f43-ccd35b8323ww", "8faf05cc063f-11e8-11e6-9f43-a6fd5780", "01e86d5b-b1c2-11e6-9fd3-ccd35b832320","ac17ba5a-debd-11e6-8865-2ce98f73fd2e"